Installing Glass panel unto a Americast bath tub
Can I drill a hole into an American Standard Americast Bathtub without damaging the tub for the purpose of install a glass shower panel. Is possible to simply silicane glass panel directly to the americast bathtub with a high grade clear adhesive caulk?

What do the instructions for the glass say?   Most times glass is bonded with silicone to a tub or shower base and mechanical fasteners are only used on walls.

YOU HAVE NO FRAME ?
